# posting to endpoint to get the redirect url before purchase

Tags: php, omnipay, guzzle

I'm trying to create a custom omnipay driver for a local gateway called creditguard.
For this gateway you need to post the data to the endpoint and get back a redirect  url for the payment form.

My question is how do you post and get the response before making the purchase?

Edit:

Gateway.php

```
    class Gateway extends AbstractGateway
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Creditguard';
    }

    public function getDefaultParameters()
    {
        return array();

    }

    public function getEndpoint()
    {
        return 'https://verifonetest.creditguard.co.il/xpo/Relay';
    }



    public function purchase(array $parameters = array())
    {
       return $this->createRequest('\Nirz\Creditguard\Message\PurchaseRequest', $parameters);

    }

    public function completePurchase(array $parameters = array())
    {
        return $this->createRequest('\Nirz\Creditguard\Message\CompletePurchaseRequest', $parameters);
    }

}
```

PurchaseRequest.php

```
  class PurchaseRequest extends AbstractRequest
{
    protected $liveEndpoint = 'https://verifonetest.creditguard.co.il/xpo/Relay';
    protected $testEndpoint = 'https://verifonetest.creditguard.co.il/xpo/Relay';


    public function getData()
    {
        $this->validate('amount');

        // Either the nodifyUrl or the returnUrl can be provided.
        // The returnUrl is deprecated, as strictly this is a notifyUrl.
        if (!$this->getNotifyUrl()) {
            $this->validate('returnUrl');
        }

        $data = array();
        $data['user'] = 'user';
        $data['password'] = 'password';
        $data['tid'] = '11111111';
        $data['mid'] = '111111';
        $data['amount'] = '20000';
        $data['int_in'] = '<ashrait>
                           <request>
                            <version>1000</version>
                            <language>HEB</language>
                            <dateTime></dateTime>
                            <command>doDeal</command>
                            <doDeal>
                                 <terminalNumber>'.$data['tid'].'</terminalNumber>
                                 <mainTerminalNumber/>
                                 <cardNo>CGMPI</cardNo>
                                 <total>'.$data['amount'].'</total>
                                 <transactionType>Debit</transactionType>
                                 <creditType>RegularCredit</creditType>
                                 <currency>ILS</currency>
                                 <transactionCode>Phone</transactionCode>
                                 <authNumber/>
                                 <numberOfPayments/>
                                 <firstPayment/>
                                 <periodicalPayment/>
                                 <validation>TxnSetup</validation>
                                 <dealerNumber/>
                                 <user>'. $data['user'] .'</user>
                                 <mid>'.$data['mid'].'</mid>
                                 <uniqueid>'.time().rand(100,1000).'</uniqueid>
                                 <mpiValidation>autoComm</mpiValidation>
                                 <email>someone@creditguard.co.il</email>
                                 <clientIP/>
                                 <customerData>
                                  <userData1/>
                                  <userData2/>
                                  <userData3/>
                                  <userData4/>
                                  <userData5/>
                                  <userData6/>
                                  <userData7/>
                                  <userData8/>
                                  <userData9/>
                                  <userData10/>
                                 </customerData>
                            </doDeal>
                           </request>
                          </ashrait>';

        return $data;
    }

    public function sendData($data)
    {
        // $httpResponse = $this->httpClient->post($this->getEndpoint(), null, $data);
        return $this->response = new PurchaseResponse($this, $data);
    }

    public function getEndpoint()
    {
        return $this->getTestMode() ? $this->testEndpoint : $this->liveEndpoint;
    }
}
```

PurchaseResponse.php

```
    class PurchaseResponse extends AbstractResponse implements RedirectResponseInterface
{
    public function isSuccessful()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function isRedirect()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function getRedirectUrl()
    {
        // return $this->getRequest()->getEndpoint().'?'.http_build_query($this->data);
        return $this->getRequest()->data['mpiHostedPageUrl'];
        // return isset($this->data['mpiHostedPageUrl']) ? $this->data['mpiHostedPageUrl'] : null;
    }

    public function getRedirectMethod()
    {
        return 'GET';
    }

    public function getRedirectData()
    {
        return [];

    }
}
```

Not sure how to get the response's mpiHostedPageUrl so I can redirect to the correct url.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, could you please describe more?

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is how to make a post request with no redirect, get the response data and then redirect to the payment form. I'm trying to use Omnipay - http://omnipay.thephpleague.com/ for that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming [this](https://cgmpiuat.creditguard.co.il/redirect_api.pdf) is the payment gateway documentation in question.

You just go ahead and make the transaction request, the customer won't be charged as they'll have to authorise it on the next page by entering in their payment details.

The response of that transaction request contains an element `mpiHostedPageUrl`, which you can see on page 13 of that document, that contains the URL you need to get from the response to provide the redirect.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that's the correct documentation. mpiHostedPageUrl is indeed what I'm trying to find after making the purchase request, I just don't understand how to get it and at what stage in a custom omnipay driver

Comment: In which case, you'll need to provide your code to show where you're at in terms of consuming the response.

Comment: I'll get a better answer to this when I get home, but in your `sendData` method, you aren't actually sending anything off to the payment provider. You're supposed to make the request there, omnipay won't handle that part for you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old question. First you need to set 'mpiHostedPageUrl' in your getData method of PurchaseRequest.php and access in PurchaseResponse.php by using $this->data['mpiHostedPageUrl'].

Answer (score -1):

HATEOAS (Hypermedia as the Engine of Application State) is a way to organize the response for REST application. 
In HATEOAS world, the response JSON may contains all URL the client may need. Example, in github API, the response contain URL for accessing to repository, user, pull request...

So, I suggest you to call the gateway with the first POST request and then, according to the JSON response, call to provided URL which will represent the redirection.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking specifically about doing this with omnipay - http://omnipay.thephpleague.com/

Answer (score -1):

Another solution could be to use a ZUUL gateway (in Spring-Boot) which will perform the redirection for you.

You can find a description here : https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/